# GCD swift 4 thread safety

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function which control some resources, for example:

```
var resource: Int?

func changeSomeResources() {
    resource = 1
    // rewriting keychain parameters
    // working with UIApplication.shared
}
```

Then I add this function to global thread several times

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    changeSomeResources()
}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    changeSomeResources()
}
```

Can I get some thread problems in this case except race condition ?
For example if both functions will try to change a resource at the same time

Comment: Whether you can have problems or not all depends on exactly what you are doing inside `changeSomeResources` but you haven't shown that code. But in general, yes, it can be a problem depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @rmaddy So, I was interested in a simple case if some global variable is thread safe by using GCD, more precisely by adding operations with DispatchQueue.async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global dispatch queues are *concurrent,* so that does not protect
your function  from being called simultaneously from multiple threads.

If you want to serialize access to the resources then you have to
create a *serial* queue:

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
```

Then all work items dispatched to this queue are executed sequentially:

```
myQueue.async {
    changeSomeResources()
}
```

Note also that `UIApplication` – as a UI related resource – must only
be accessed on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // working with UIApplication.shared
}
```

Xcode also has options “Thread Sanitizer” and “Main Thread Checker” 
(in the “Diagnostics” pane of the scheme settings) which can help
to detect threading problems.